# Tkinter Menubutton widget key binding to open Menu widget elements in same window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, submenu

I have created a submenu inside a menu using `Menubutton` and `Menu` widgets:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def f(event):
    submenu.invoke(0)

mainmenu = Menubutton(root, text="Menu")
mainmenu.pack()

submenu = Menu(mainmenu)
mainmenu.config(menu=submenu)

submenu.add_command(label="Option 1")
submenu.add_command(label="Option 2")
```

Now I want to add a key binding to my menu:

```
mainmenu.bind("<Key>", f)
mainmenu.focus_set()
```

It works as charm: when I press a key, it opens up the submenu. But the problem is, the submenu is opened as a torn off toplevel window. But I want it to be opened in same window with menu. I added `tearoff=0` into `submenu` (so it became like this:`submenu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)`). But now, it does not return anything. I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't. Maybe I'm doing something wrong...
 I have looked for a solution, but none of them solves the problem. All they tell is just adding a key binding that prints out something, however I want a key binding that kinda automatically clicks on a menu item, and it pops up the item elements, but not as a separate window (maybe it's called `contextmenu`?). I couldn't find any solution to this specific problem anywhere.
So how can I make it happen? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to create a menu that isn't actually a menu? If it's not a popup window. how do you expect it to appear? What do you mean by "opened in same window with menu"?

Comment: I want the submenu to not torn off.

Comment: Again, it works as charm when I do not use `tearoff=0`, but when I add this functionality, it does not return anything. That's weird.

Answer (score 4):

I think

```
def f(event):
    submenu.post(mainmenu.winfo_rootx(), 
                 mainmenu.winfo_rooty() + mainmenu.winfo_height())
```

does what you want, even with the `tearoff=False` option.

Comment: This way is the best solution so far. I had to include it in my code. I actually expect more "natural" way though.