# Tkinter Menubutton items disapper

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a vallid code

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()

mb=  Menubutton ( top, text="CheckComboBox", relief=RAISED )
mb.grid()
mb.menu  =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0 )
mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu

Item0 = IntVar()
Item1 = IntVar()
Item2 = IntVar()

mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Item0", variable=Item0)
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Item1", variable=Item1)
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Item2", variable=Item2)

mb.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

When I click to "CheckComboBox" I see list of items.
Then I click to "Item1" and list of items disapper and I have to click to "CheckComboBox" many times if I want to choose a few items.

I want "list of times" don't disappeares after click to Item.

[image]

Comment: This is probably not a very good idea because then after the user has selected all the items in the menu, it would still not close, so user has to click elsewhere for it to lose focus and close. I dont think any default methods exist for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("%ix%i" % (50, 50))

def raise_menubutton(*args):
    # Open the menu again. Taken from:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676204/11106801
    menubutton.menu.post(menubutton.winfo_rootx(), 
                menubutton.winfo_rooty() + menubutton.winfo_height())

menubutton = tk.Menubutton(root, text="CheckComboBox", relief="raised")
menubutton.grid()
menubutton.menu = tk.Menu(menubutton, tearoff=0)
menubutton["menu"] = menubutton.menu

menubutton.menu.bind("<Button-1>", raise_menubutton)

Item0 = tk.IntVar()
Item1 = tk.IntVar()
Item2 = tk.IntVar()

# Bind to variables changing
Item0.trace("w", raise_menubutton)
Item1.trace("w", raise_menubutton)
Item2.trace("w", raise_menubutton)

menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Item0", variable=Item0)
menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Item1", variable=Item1)
menubutton.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Item2", variable=Item2)

menubutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Works on Windows at least.

Answer (score 0):

Menu behavior like this is defined by the OS / window manager, and tkinter doesn't provide any way to control it.