# Tkinter dropdown menu not retracting

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create an app in tkinter that has a dropdown menu which allows multiple selections in once. The problem is that when I select an option the menu retracts and I have to re-open it manually to select the next option.
Is there a way to make the dropdown menu to stay open until, let's say, click somewhere else in or outside the app or until I click on the top of the dropdown menu again?

```
import tkinter as tk

def update_selected_options(option, var, selected_options):
    if var.get():
        selected_options.append(option)
    else:
        selected_options.remove(option)
    print(selected_options)

def select_option(option, var, selected_options):
    update_selected_options(option, var, selected_options)

def create_dropdown(parent, options):
    selected_options = []

    # create menubutton
    menubutton = tk.Menubutton(parent, text="Choose options", indicatoron=True, borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
    menu = tk.Menu(menubutton, tearoff=True)
    menubutton.configure(menu=menu)
    menubutton.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    # add checkbuttons to menu
    for option in options:
        var = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
        menu.add_checkbutton(label=option, variable=var, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, command=lambda option=option, var=var: select_option(option, var, selected_options))

    # keep menu open after an option is selected
    menu.postcommand = lambda: menubutton.config(state="active")

    return menubutton

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
    menubutton = create_dropdown(root, options)
    root.mainloop()
```

I found this `menu.postcommand = lambda: menubutton.config(state="active")` but it doesn't seem to do the job correctly

Comment: Configuring the `state` of the menubutton just changes if the button is selectable or not, it does not open (post), or close the drop-down menu. Try by adding `menubutton.config(state="disabled")` to your code. See [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/menubutton.html) for documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some minor changes to your code, but the main line to solve your issue is `menu.post(menubutton.winfo_rootx(), menubutton.winfo_rooty() + menubutton.winfo_height())`. I got it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674365/tkinter-menubutton-widget-key-binding-to-open-menu-widget-elements-in-same-windo) question. Basically it re-opens your `drop-down menu` at the position of your `menubutton` every time the function `select_option` is called. You can get the idea when you add for example `+100` to the x or y coordinate.

```
import tkinter as tk


def select_option(option, var):
    global selected_options

    if var.get():
        selected_options.append(option)
    else:
        selected_options.remove(option)
    print(selected_options)

    menu.post(menubutton.winfo_rootx(), menubutton.winfo_rooty() + menubutton.winfo_height())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]

    selected_options = []

    # create menubutton
    menubutton = tk.Menubutton(root, text="Choose options", indicatoron=True, activeforeground='blue', highlightcolor='blue', borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
    menu = tk.Menu(menubutton, tearoff=False, activeborderwidth=10, activeforeground='blue')
    menubutton.configure(menu=menu)
    menubutton.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    # add checkbuttons to menu
    for option in options:
        var = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
        menu.add_checkbutton(label=option, variable=var, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, command=lambda option=option, var=var: select_option(option, var))
    
    root.mainloop()
```